# Gradle equivalent of Maven javadoc:fix

Tags: maven, gradle, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

Is there any plugin for gradle that performs similar to maven's `mvn javadoc:fix`. It would be easy to create javadoc if there any plugin like that.

Comment: https://github.com/melix/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin perhaps?

Comment: @PerrynFowler I think the plugin you mentioned to fix a vulnerability in javadoc already generated. what i need is a plugin that can generate/update the javadoc as maven javadoc:fix do.